# IPs errors with simple visitors counter PHP

Tags: php, sql, ip

I built a simple visitors counter in PHP, it saves visitors IPs inside my database.

This is my script:

```
function view_count() {
    global $bdd;
    $ip   = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $query = $bdd->prepare("
        INSERT INTO views_stats (ip , date_visite , pages_vues, subcategory_id) VALUES (:ip , :date , 1, :subcategory_id)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pages_vues = pages_vues + 1
    ");
    $query->execute(array(
        ':ip'   => $ip,
        ':date' => $date,
        ':subcategory_id' => $_GET['s']
    ));
}
```

It doesn't work properly, sometimes it doesn't save the IP visitor.

IPs in my database:

```
66.249.64.21
2a03:2880:2111:bfdc:face:b00c:
2a01:e34:ee35:2ad0:3c49:4e42:b
185.20.6.14
34.201.147.172
212.227.247.118
```

I don't understand why sometimes I have `2a01:e34:ee35:2ad0:3c49:4e42:b` instead of an ip address.

Any idea? thx

Comment: `66.249.64.21` = IPv4. `2a03:2880:2111:bfdc:face:b00c:` = IPv6. They are both IP addresses.

Comment: @Jon Thx I didn't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are ip addresses one for ipv4 and second is ipv6 thats why it's not working you can change your data type to solve issue. also you can find all details about ipv4 and ipv6 [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/01/ip-address-fundamentals/) you will get better idea.

Comment: thanks for you explain and link, I will fix my script.